# How to use same sql query for multiple dates?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have the following select query

```
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE birth_date >= TO_DATE(:start_date1, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
  AND birth_date <= TO_DATE(:end_date1, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
) AS count1
```

I also need to find the count for `start_date2` and `end_date2` which would result in separate variable `count2`

What would be the best way to get `count2`?

I rewrote the query and replaced `start_date1` and `end_date1` with `start_date2` and `end_date2`. Is there any other way without rewriting the query?

Comment: I've never seen this syntax where you create an alias inside of a WHERE clause, seems weird. You aren't even using the alias anyways so I don't understand your question

Comment: Guessing this is part of a bigger query. I would say there are three options to consider. Create a stored procedure that can be called with parametrised dates, or, if your windows for birthdate are consistent use a group by and align the date to start or end of the month, or an ‘execute immediate’ approach with declared variables.

Comment: hi @GrumpyCoruton, yes you are right, this is part of a bigger select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can join with a subquery that returns each date, and then use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT t1.start_date, t1.end_date, COALESCE(COUNT(t2.birth_date), 0) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT :start_date1 AS start_date, :end_date1 AS end_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT :start_date2 AS start_date, :end_date2 AS end_date
) t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE t2 ON t2.birth_date BETWEEN t1.start_date AND t1.end_date
GROUP BY t1.start_date, t1.end_date
```

Comment: This is not a valid Oracle query as `IFNULL` is not supported and you cannot use `AS` before a table/inline view alias. Apart from that you also have a syntax error with `.` instead of `,`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that the question was Oracle, assumed MySQL.

Comment: Fixed the syntax errors and switched to `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to only query the table once:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN birth_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(:start_date1, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
                             AND TO_DATE(:end_date1, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS count1,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN birth_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(:start_date2, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
                             AND TO_DATE(:end_date2, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS count2
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  birth_date BETWEEN LEAST(TO_DATE(:start_date1, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), TO_DATE(:start_date2, 'YYYY/MM/DD'))
                      AND GREATEST(TO_DATE(:end_date1, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), TO_DATE(:end_date2, 'YYYY/MM/DD'))
```

If you want to use it as part of a large query then `CROSS JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT d.*,
       c.count1,
       c.count2
FROM   DUAL d
       CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT COUNT(
                  CASE
                  WHEN birth_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(:start_date1, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
                                      AND TO_DATE(:end_date1, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
                  THEN 1
                  END
                ) AS count1,
                COUNT(
                  CASE
                  WHEN birth_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(:start_date2, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
                                      AND TO_DATE(:end_date2, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
                  THEN 1
                  END
                ) AS count2
         FROM   TABLE
         WHERE  birth_date BETWEEN LEAST(TO_DATE(:start_date1, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), TO_DATE(:start_date2, 'YYYY/MM/DD'))
                               AND GREATEST(TO_DATE(:end_date1, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), TO_DATE(:end_date2, 'YYYY/MM/DD'))
       ) c;
```